# Eclipse Android - Parser Exception in Manifest

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, ddms

I was developing an application for Android in Eclipse Juno using ADT. For some reason, I suddenly got errors in my program (which was very simple: I added some items to the menu and that's it) and for some reason, my project seemed to get errors, as trying to run it resulted in failure due to my project containing errors. The weird thing is, neither my menu XML file nor my main activity showed any errors, just the project as a whole. This, in turn, deletes my R.java file when I try to clean my project. Now, when I try and remake a "Graphics" project, I get this DDMS error before I ever make any modifications:

```
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for    /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - Graphics] Parser exception for /Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
 [2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
 [2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
[2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
 [2012-08-08 14:54:24 - com.android.ide.eclipse.adt.internal.project.AndroidManifestHelper] Parser exception for /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
 [2012-08-08 14:54:25 - Graphics] Parser exception for /Graphics/AndroidManifest.xml: The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.
```

I have no idea what is causing this now. I haven't made any modifications to my libraries. I was running tests just fine in another workspace before this. Can anyone explain what is going on?

Here's my Manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.graphics"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>

</manifest><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.graphics"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
</application>

</manifest><manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.graphics"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Here's my main layout, where I'm getting the error mentioned in yugidroid's answer:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

AFAIK, your manifest only can have one root `manfiest` tag and you have 3! Why?

Try to us something like I show you below:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.graphics"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"
    android:targetSdkVersion="15" />

<application
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Let me know about your progress.

**EDIT:**

The samething happens with your layout. A layout file only can have one root tag (eg, `RelativeLayout`, `LienarLayout`, etc).
Try to replace your layout file content with the following one:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:text="@string/hello_world"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: I have no idea why... It just started like that.

Comment: I get this error now: `[2012-08-08 15:53:05 - Graphics] /scratch/android-source/bin/sdk/emulator/platform-tools/aapt: /lib/libz.so.1: no version information available (required by /scratch/android-source/bin/sdk/emulator/platform-tools/aapt)
[2012-08-08 15:53:05 - Graphics] /nfs/guille/groce/users/nicholsk/workspace3/Graphics/res/layout/activity_main.xml:15: error: Error parsing XML: junk after document element`

Comment: @NioShobu, have you tried my posted manifest? You're getting getting an error in the `activity_main.xm‌​l` layout file. Can you post it on your question too?

Comment: I had a HelloWorld application which I deleted and checked the option to also delete contents from my hard drive. I later created another HelloWorld project and then I got this problem. After reading your answer, I noticed that I also had duplicate XML elements in my manifest and layout files. Removing them fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 6):

I just ran into this same problem, and I think I've figured out what's happening. What happened for me what that I had a project named Foo that worked completely fine the first time, but I deleted the project (checking the option to delete project contents on disk). Now, when I created another project with the same name (Foo), I got the error that you have here. Actually, if you delete the project and re-create it multiple times, it will add in/duplicate the whole manifest section each time.

Did you by any chance have a project with the same name (Graphics) some time before that you deleted, and then started a new one with the same name?

Comment: the same thing happened with me. Deleting the duplicate XML elements from manifest and layout files fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Your having an XML parsing problem so the Andorid_Manifest.xml code would help.

An example manifest looks like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.your.package"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, trying to create a project of the same name. The disk was clean all deleted but it took a restart of eclipse to allow an error free generation.